# Use MacOSX framework compiled with different version

Tags: macos, compiler-construction, frameworks

From what I've heard, it's possible to use a DLL in Windows that is compiled with a different compiler version. Does MacOSX frameworks have the same functionality? That is, can I compile a framework with one compiler and then use that framework in a program that uses a different compiler version?

The reason why I ask is that need to compile a open source project that outputs a framework. That project is not possible to build with gcc4.7 and my code uses gcc4.7 features.